# Jolt : Add key in sub object

Tags: jolt

Input

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sample name",
    "attributes": {
        "age": 10
    }
}
```

Output

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "attributes": {
        "name": "Sample name",
        "age": 10
    }
}
```

I want to carry out this transformation. I tried with the below spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "name": "attributes.&"
    }
  }
]
```

But this changes `attributes` field into an array. What should be the right spec used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following spec would work

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&",
      "name": "attributes.&",
      "attributes": {
        "*": "attributes.&"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you also know why the spec I tried doesn't work? Shouldn't the wildcard copy attributes as is?

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact reason. But I guess what happens in your spec is this. Since `name` field is found first in the JSON, an `attributes` field is set to the output with the `name` property first. Then when the processor found the existing `attributes` field on the input, it again tries to set the `attributes` field to output considering its value as a whole object. So since there is already a field with the same name, `attributes` becomes an array.

Comment: In my spec, the `attributes` field is not set as a whole. But the processor iterates through the properties of `attributes` object and set them one by one. So they are being set to the same field that was set earlier with the `name` property.